# How to create a directory and copy files into it with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have some files in Pictures\ with extension *.png and directories like 12-21-20, 12-20-20. These directories was created with dir=`mkdir $(date +'%m'-'%d'-'%Y')`

At the end of the day I want to run a script which will create a folder $dir and copy all png files I've made for today into that folder. How can I do that? Any information you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`date +'%m-%d-%Y'` is the `date` command outputting, e,g. `12-22-2020`. `$(..)` is called *command substitution* that captures the result of the `date` command allowing it to be assigned to the variable `dir`.

To create a directory with the contents of `$dir` (e.g. `12-22-2020`) you would use the `mkdir` command, providing the `-p` option to suppress the error if that directory already exists (and also create parent directories as necessary -- not relevant here). You want to ensure it succeeds before you attempt to copy files to the new directory, so you would use:

```
mkdir -p "$dir" || exit 1
```

Which simply exits if the command fails.

At this point, you can simply use `cp` (or preferably `mv` to move the files) from whatever source directory they currently reside in. That you can do with:

```
mv /path/to/source/dir/*.png "$dir"
```

Or the copy command,

```
cp -a /path/to/source/dir/*.png "$dir"
```

Both `cp -a` and `mv` will preserve the original file attributes (time, date, permissions, etc...).

From a script standpoint, you will either want to change to the directory above the new `"$dir"` or use the full path, e.g.

```
mv /path/to/source/dir/*.png "/path/to/$dir"
```

**Short Example**

If you want to provide the directory containing the `.png` files to move to `"$dir"` created with today's date, you could write a short script like the following. You provide the directory containing the `.png` files you would like to copy or move as the first argument to the script on the command-line, e.g. usage would be `bash pngscript.sh /path/to/source/dir`.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && {   ## validate one argument given for source directory
    printf "usage: ./%s /path/to/images" "${0##*/}" >&2
    exit 1
}

[ "$(ls -1 "$1"/*.png | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] || {        ## validate png files in source dir
    printf "error: no .png files in '%s'\n" "$1" >&2
    exit 1
} 

dir=$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')         ## get current date

mkdir -p "$dir" || exit 1       ## create directory, exit on failure

mv "$1"/*.png "$dir"            ## move .png files from source to "$dir"
```

(**note:** it will create the `"$dir"` directory below the current working directory and then move files from the path provided as the first argument (positional parameter) to the newly created directory. Change `mv` to `cp -a` if you want to leave a copy of the files in the original directory)

You can make the script executable with `chmod +x pngscript.sh` and then you can simply run it from the current directory as:

```
./pngscript.sh /path/to/source/dir
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you. You've been very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you have questions and I'm happy to help further. Good luck with your scripting!